How to install Azure Cognitive Services Speech from source
I want to install Azure Cognitive Services Speech SDK in Python. On a Macbook, I can run:
python3 -m pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech

and it works.
On an iMac, the same command throws:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure-cognitiveservices-speech (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for azure-cognitiveservices-speech

Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425580/cant-pip-microsoft-azure-cognitiveservices-speech, I confirm that the hardware is 64-bit:
$ getconf LONG_BIT
64

and that Python is 64-bit too:
$ python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
64

Following this Microsoft learn thread, I upgraded pip and tried to install with --pre:
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --pre azure-cognitiveservices-speech

and I get the same error.
The next step is to install from source:


If the above steps don't work, you can try installing the package from the source code. Clone the GitHub repository for the azure-cognitiveservices-speech package and run the command python3 setup.py install to install the package.


The PyPI page does not link to Github. On the Github Microsoft repositories, I could only find SDKs for JS and Go. I could not find it either with an online search for this repo.
The last step is to use DockerHub:


If none of the above steps work, you can try using a Docker container with the azure-cognitiveservices-speech package pre-installed. You can find Docker images for the package on the Docker Hub.


But I find nothing on DockerHub when I search for azure-cognitiveservices-speech.
Where is the source code for the package, or how else can I install Microsoft Cognitive Services?

On Windows or macOS, you can bypass these issues of the Python SDK with the aspeak (Azure-speak) package.
Similar to the Python SDK, it is a wrapper to synthesize speech from Microsoft, but it's more well-maintained (GitHub repo, e.g. one issue I posted yesterday got an answer in a few hours) and can use the REST API, so it probably won't have those same issues in the future.
Install it with:
python3 -m pip install aspeak

then call it with:
import aspeak

service = aspeak.SpeechService(
    region="westeurope",
    key="Your Microsoft API key"
)
service.synthesize_ssml(some_ssml, output=output_filepath)

The SSML has to follow the Microsoft standards, e.g.:
<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xmlns:mstts='https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts' xml:lang='pt-pt'><voice name='pt-PT-RaquelNeural'>Olá crianças! Como se sentem? Eu sinto-me contente.</voice></speak>

Unortunately, Linux is not supported:

Because of manylinux compatibility issues, the wheels for linux are not published. You need to build it by yourself.


When you visit PyPi page, go to Download Files tab. There, you can find Build Distributions. Download the .whl file available for macOS 10.14+ x86_64. Link
Once you have downloaded the file, you can run
python3 -m pip install ~/Downloads/azure_cognitiveservices_speech-1.37.0-py3-none-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl

It should install your required package.
NOTE: Minimum macOS version for your required package is 10.14. Please check it for your iMac once. This might be the issue.

Thanks for the tip on the distribution. Version 1.18.0 of azure-cognitiveservices-speech is the last to be compatible with MacOS 10.12+, and from 1.19 it's only for MacOS 10.14+. Nevertheless, python3 -m pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.18.0 throws the same error, and following your steps with the distribution of 1.18.0, for any of cp36, cp37, cp38 or cp39 throws ERROR: azure_cogntiveservices_speech-1.18.0-cp39-cpp39-macosx_10_12_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
